# How to detect event checked radio input in ajax load form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, uikit

i'm using Uikit radio input (https://altair-html.tzdthemes.com/forms_regular.html).

The problem is the radio input is transforming between code and on site display
After load my form with Ajax, i want to alert value for radio choice after each change.

Here my code :
HTML :

```
<div class="uk-width-medium-1-2">
<h5>Radio set 1</h5>
<div class="uk-grid" data-uk-grid-margin>
    <span class="icheck-inline">
        <input type="radio" name="radio_opt" id="radio_opt_1" value="Yes" data-md-icheck />
        <label for="radio_opt_1" class="inline-label">Oui</label>
    </span>
    <span class="icheck-inline">
        <input type="radio" name="radio_opt" id="radio_opt_2" value="Non" data-md-icheck />
        <label for="radio_opt_2" class="inline-label">No</label>
    </span>
</div>
</div>
<div class="uk-width-medium-1-2">
<h5>Radio set 2</h5>
<div class="uk-grid" data-uk-grid-margin>
    <span class="icheck-inline">
        <input type="radio" name="radio_opt_second" id="radio_opt_3" value="Yes" data-md-icheck />
        <label for="radio_opt_3" class="inline-label">Oui</label>
    </span>
    <span class="icheck-inline">
        <input type="radio" name="radio_opt_second" id="radio_opt_4" value="Non" data-md-icheck />
        <label for="radio_opt_4" class="inline-label">No</label>
    </span>
</div>
</div>
```

Then here my JS (doesnt' work)

```
$(document).on('change', 'input:radio', function () {
     alert('test');
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by `transforming between code and on site display`? It seems to be working: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s7jq46bk/).

Comment: Thx for your help, if you check the URL, you'll see the input radio is remplaced by <ins> element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That theme is using [iCheck](https://github.com/dargullin/icheck) and according to the docs you should use:

```
$('input:radio').on('ifChecked', function(event) {
     alert('test');
});
```